# global.asax does not work

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I am developing an asp.net web application and i have a problem with `Global.asax` file,
when i publish my website and upload it to server the `Global.asax` is missed, it will be gone to bin folder and Reshape to Dll file.
but it does not work!

and when i uploaded the `Global.asax` file to the root folder it works but i have an other error like this

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'ASP.global_asax' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\93c82a26\eca26fde\assembly\dl3\b8f9aab8\18e0a0de_5afccf01\App_global.asax.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\93c82a26\eca26fde\App_global.asax.o53z7epf.dll'

protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
           get {
               return ((ASP.global_asax)(this.Context.ApplicationInstance));
```

and its not possible to clear the temp folder because there will be on other error, please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem occurred in a virtual application's bin folder. When you look into this bin-folder you will probably see two files (an information I found [here](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/1/compiler-error-globalasax-exists-multiple-times/)):

> - App_global.asax.dll
> - App_global.asax.compiled

Removing these resolves the error. The App_global.asax.dll is generated at runtime too which causes the problem.

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: But what if I want to precompile all of my website? It doesn't make sense to just remove them.